# Verificar se existe a palavra na string usando array de strings e separar a string em uma nova array

Tags: javascript, array, string, funções

Estou em um problema onde eu quero que uma string se torne uma array com as palavras separadas, só que o código retorna arrays duplicadas

```
    var string = 'xicara,cafecafe';
    var array1 = ['casa', 'xicara', 'xicarada', 'xicrinha', 'xi', 'carro', 'cafe', ',', 'ca'];
    function extrair(str, arr) {
        var encontradas = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            arr.forEach(function (match, index) {
                if (str.slice(i).indexOf(match) == 0) {
                    encontradas.push(match);
                };
            });
        }
        return encontradas;
    }
    var array2 = extrair(string, array1);
    console.log(array2); //  ["xicara", "xi", "ca", ",", "cafe", "ca"];
```

Eu queria que a array2 tivesse os valores iguais o da string, tipo assim:

```
console.log(array2); //  ['xicara', ',', 'cafe', 'cafe'];
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Como iria saber que `cafecafe` são duas palavras? Só da para faze dessa maneira se interpretar ao contrário, partindo do array de matches, percorrendo e fazendo `indexOf` na `var string`, mas potencialmente trás outros problemas

Comment: então não tem como fazer  com que a saída seja  ['xicara', ',', 'cafe', 'cafe']; ao invés de ["xicara", "xi", "ca", ",", "cafe", "ca", "cafe", "ca"]?

Comment: O problema e solução tá na forma como `'xicara,cafecafe'` foi construido e não no algoritmo apresentado na pergunta. Tem que haver uma forma univoca de identeificar cada palavra/token nessa string caso contrário não será possivel